# Where can I find a non-deprecated geofence sample code for Android Studio 3.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-location, android-geofence

Strange question to ask but I'm having trouble with finding a working code sample for geofencing on Android. It looks like there are a few official geofencing samples:

1. [Deprecated Android Geofencing app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Geofencing)
2. [Sample code for Kotlin](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7372-geofencing-api-tutorial-for-android)
3. [Creating and Monitoring Geofences](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/Geofencing)

I've inherited a Java app, so #2 doesn't work for me. With #3, I had some build failures until I added the following to my gradle.properties file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

With the build working, I tried running the app on the emulator with the Pixel 2 API 28. I signed into the Play store, toggled the "Google Location Accuracy" ON, enabled both Wifi and Bluetooth scanning and received the following logs:

```
2019-01-14 23:38:43.597 25221-25221/? I/mple.geofencin: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-01-14 23:38:43.636 25221-25221/? W/mple.geofencin: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-01-14 23:38:44.134 25221-25221/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing W/mple.geofencin: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-01-14 23:38:44.135 25221-25221/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing W/mple.geofencin: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-01-14 23:38:44.328 25221-25221/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing I/MainActivity: Requesting permission
2019-01-14 23:38:44.393 25221-25221/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2019-01-14 23:38:44.470 25221-25254/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-01-14 23:38:44.470 25221-25254/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-01-14 23:38:44.471 25221-25254/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-01-14 23:38:44.471 25221-25254/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-01-14 23:38:44.471 25221-25254/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-01-14 23:38:44.472 25221-25254/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-01-14 23:38:44.484 25221-25254/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe14051e0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2019-01-14 23:38:44.505 25221-25254/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe14051e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe1403660)
2019-01-14 23:38:44.679 25221-25254/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe14051e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe1403660)
2019-01-14 23:38:47.961 25221-25221/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing I/MainActivity: onRequestPermissionResult
2019-01-14 23:38:47.961 25221-25221/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing I/MainActivity: Permission granted.
2019-01-14 23:38:53.437 25221-25254/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe14051e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe1403660)
2019-01-14 23:38:53.442 25221-25254/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe14051e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe1403660)
2019-01-14 23:40:18.152 25221-25241/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 1928 bytes, containing 1 windows, 16 views
2019-01-14 23:40:20.314 25221-25254/com.google.android.gms.location.sample.geofencing D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe14051e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe1403660)
```

Even after changing the location to SFO/GOOGLE in the emulator, there were no notifications on the emulator. I added a print statement in `onHandleWork` in `GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService` but it looked like no geofence events were fired.

I also tried on a real Pixel device with Fake GPS; no notifications either. So, my question is what sample code should we be using for Geofencing? Is it supposed to work on the emulator? Does it work on a real phone if I switch the app to the background to change the location in the Fake GPS app?

PS: My emulator image has Google Play enabled
PPS: I tried this XYZ Tourist Attractions app too; I could see the distances change when I changed the GPS location via the emulator but still no notifications. I didn't dig too far into this though.
PPPS: Please help!

Update 1:

- I do receive the geofence transitions events.. but only if Google
  maps is running in the foreground. I'm not sure if this is because
  I'm setting the location via the emulator...
- The build break in (3) seems to be a regression in the googlesamples repo from the update from 5 days ago. Commit `432d3b72b8c058f220416958b444274ddd186abd` seems to build out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working with GeoFence for such a long time, I had the same question and I got the answer by myself after trying different solutions, So basically, GeoFence only get triggers if any app in the phone is fetching the location for some x duration. If you test the GeoFence sample app provided by google then you can see that the app works only when you open the Google maps application, its because Google Maps is the only app in the device that requests locations passively.

For Prove you can clone GeoFence sample and the LocationUpdateForGroundService sample from this below link https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location Run both of them GeoFence and LocationUpdateForGroundService at the same time, You will notice by changing the lat and long from the emulator that now you dont need to open Google maps any more because now there is another app which is requesting location.

So do create a foreground service in the GeoFence application and use Fuse Location Client to request location updates for some x duration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I realized that geofences were triggered only when Google Maps was running too; it is strange that their geofence samples do not explicitly tell you about this. I'll have to create background services to handle the location requests but it seems like [this tutorial] (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) has got me covered.

Comment: Yeah, They haven't mentioned this important information any where.

Comment: Google docs is the worst place to look for working code or meaningful explanation. But it is good if you are looking for obsolete and non-working code and tons of missing information.